# Parse Lines of Single Words and Groups of Words Inside Quotes Using Regular Expressions in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, parsing, text

I'm trying to figure out how to better parse lines of text that have values that look like this:

```
line1  
'Line two' fudgy whale 'rolly polly'  
fudgy 'line three' whale  
fudgy whale 'line four'  
'line five' 'fish heads' 
line six
```

I wish to use **a single regular expression** to display the desired output. I already know how to kludge it up to get the desired output but **I want a single expression**.

**Desired output**:

```
["line1"]
["Line two", "fudgy", "whale", "rolly polly"]
["fudgy", "line three", "whale"]
["fudgy", "whale", "line four"]
["line five", "fish heads"]
["line", "six"]
```

The line reading is already handled for me via Cucumber. Each line is read as one string value and I want to parse out single words and any number of words contained inside single quotes. I know less than nothing about regular expressions but I've hobbled together a regular expression using the regex "or" operator ("|") that got me close.

Taking that regex I first tried parsing each line using a string split:

```
text_line.split(/(\w+)|'(.*?)'/)
```

Which resulted in the following, less than acceptable, arrays:

```
["", "line1"]
["", "Line two", " ", "fudgy", " ", "whale", " ", "rolly polly"]
["", "fudgy", " ", "line three", " ", "whale"]
["", "fudgy", " ", "whale", " ", "line four"]
["", "line five", " ", "fish heads"]
["", "line", "", "six"]
```

I next tried using scan instead of a split and I saw this:

```
text_line.scan(/(\w+)|'(.*?)'/)
[["line1", nil]]
[[nil, "Line two"], ["fudgy", nil], ["whale", nil], [nil, "rolly polly"]]
[["fudgy", nil], [nil, "line three"], ["whale", nil]]
[["fudgy", nil,], ["whale", nil], [nil, "line four"]]
[[nil, "line five"], [nil, "fish heads"]]
[["line", nil], [nil, "six",]]
```

So I could see the regex "or" operator was producing a value for each possible "or" position which made sense. Knowing that I figured out I could use scan, flatten, and compact to clean it up giving me the **desired output**:

```
text_line.scan(/(\w+)|'(.*?)'/).flatten.compact
["line1"]
["Line two", "fudgy", "whale", "rolly polly"]
["fudgy", "line three", "whale"]
["fudgy", "whale", "line four"]
["line five", "fish heads"]
["line", "six"]
```

But using the scan, flatten, and compact looks incredibly ugly and it seems like I'm just monkey patching my own bad regular expression. I'm thinking instead of ham-handedly fixing the sloppy output from my poorly constructed regex I should just write a better regular expression.

So, **is it possible to use a single regular expression to parse the above lines and get the desired output**? I may be way off on the regex to begin with but I'm thinking if I could just somehow group the or's so they only return one value per group that would probably be what I'm looking for.

Please feel free to suggest alternate solutions but **I'm looking for elegant solutions done the Ruby way** since I'm trying to teach myself how to use the language.

Thanks in advance for your time.

**edited to incorporate tininfi's better, more accurate regex**

Comment: Oh, it's too long to read all of your descriptions, could you make it simpler? Do you want to extract every *words contained inside single quotes* in every lines?

Comment: Or just make words `desired output` bold

Comment: If I was too verbose I apologize. I've already stated in my text what my desired output is but have copied it to the top to make it more clear. The reason I didn't do this in the first place was I wanted people helping to have read what I've already tried so they don't waste their time repeating it.  Also since I describe what I'm looking for at the end of the question if you don't read the entire question you won't understand what I'm asking for.

Comment: You have pre-determined the "elegant" solution will be a regular expression. Elegant code is simple and easy to "grok" while still accomplishing complex things. Elegant code can be spread across multiple lines if that is what is required to be accomplish the task; It is its simplicity when accomplishing the objective that makes it elegant. Regex patterns that do complex things are seldom simple or easy to understand because they are basically built from line-noise, so I think your prerequisites are in conflict.

Comment: I haven't necessarily determined elegant to mean a regular expression but since elegance is in the eye of the beholder I get to decide what I think is elegant. To me replacing a single line of easily understood code with several lines that require you to do some mental parsing is not only less elegant it's less grok-able. Saying a complex regex pattern is inelegant it is a bit like saying a French grade school book is complex and inelegant because you don't read French.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simplify the regex to:

```
'(.*?)'|(\w+)
```

You still have to use the flatten and compact, but at least it is a bit nicer looking. Not that you specified the need, but this will allow for the string:

```
'quote one' 'quote two'
```

*Below was rejected as less elegant than original solution.*
<strike>You could try:</strike>

```
regex = %r((\w+)|(?:')([^"\r\n]*)(?:'))
text.split(regex).delete_if { |x| x.strip.empty? }
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort. This is actually less elegant than the solution I've already come up with; the focus of my question is how to write a better regular expression. Thanks for the try though.

Comment: You get the "answered." You not only fixed a bug in my regex, you made the code cleaner. And yes, more elegant. Now if I can manage to go a few months without saying that word again...

Comment: Well, I am glad it helped. I still wish I could find the solution that does not require a flatten and compact. Thanks for helping me get my first few points here. Happy coding!

Comment: @Nakilon. You had an extra step in there, the map, plus Tinifini's regex is cleaner. But I voted up your answer too. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get array of arrays of different size, you may do it in two steps: `.split` and `.scan`.
In your case `.scan` has `()` on two sides of `|`, that's why you have trouble with `nil` (Which supposed to be useful, but not it your case). So you have either use `.flatten.compact` or add the 3rd step of `.delete`.

```
text.split("\n").map{|i|p i.scan(/'([^']+)'|(\w+)/).flatten.compact}
text.split("\n").map{|i|p i.scan(/'[^']+'|\w+/).map{|i|i.delete "'"}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You're covering ground I'm already using or have rejected. My main focus is on doing the most "correct" Ruby which avoids the sloppy programming I'm using now. I am however very appreciative of your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that you still don't like this, but this is the closest thing to "a single regular expression" I could come up with:

```
text_line.scan(/(?<=')(?:[^\s][^']*)(?=')|(?:\w+)/)
```

This breaks if the input text has a quoted word that starts with a space.